# Bug de escaping

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Achei um bug de um problema de escape de strings no nome das tags no link do feed de RSS, tal como no screenshot abaixo.

[image: Problema de escape]

Comment: Eles vão ter que fazer uma revisão geral disso, tá cheio de problemas assim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't replicate the bug, it has probably been fixed.

Comment: It's fixed: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/442/bug-na-acentuacao-fora-das-tags